# Why does a Java coded HTTP GET deliver a different web page than a seemingly identical Firefox GET request?

Tags: java, http, firefox, get

I want to load my own TMF player page from a Java program to automatically derive decision points. URL is "http://caps.fool.com/player/staka.aspx". Firefox loads the page (all Cookies removed, not logged in) as expected. It protocols the GET request as shown here:

> Request-URL:  http://caps.fool.com/player/staka.aspx
>     Request-Methode:  GET
>     Status-Code:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>     Request-Header 12:03:26.000
>     User-Agent:   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
>     Host: caps.fool.com
>     DNT:  1
>     Connection:   keep-alive
>     Cache-Control:    max-age=0
>     Accept-Language:  de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>     Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
>     Accept:   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

I try to code this as close as possible:

> ```
>   URL url = new URL("http://caps.fool.com/player/staka.aspx"); 
>   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
>   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
>   connection.setRequestProperty(
>     "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0");
>   connection.setRequestProperty("Host", url.getHost());
>   connection.setRequestProperty("DNT", "1");
>   connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
>   connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
>   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
>   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
>   connection.setRequestProperty(
>     "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
>   inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
>   ...
> ```

Nevertheless I get a different page containing the following:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
> <script>
> (function() { 
> var z="";var b="747279 ... 7D3B";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z =  z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
> </script></head>
> <body>
> <iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="http://my.incapsula.com/public/ga/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
> </body></html>
> ```

I have shortened a rather long string of digits by "...". In this returned page they show a no-robots hint which is not contained in the original page which I intend to access. I see that they use technology from "incapsula.com" which probably helps them to see a difference between my GET and the one from Firefox. I experimented a lot with the various parameters and others but nothing lead to different results.

Shouldn't it be possible to program a GET request which is indistinguishable from the one created by Firefox? Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: try selenium. when you send a get request then your browser downloads js and images. if you dont request for them it probably means you are a bot. also some people check for mouse movement.

Comment: The browser can only download js and images when it got the page! The Java request does not deliver the page.

Comment: actualy you are right, try removing `DNT,Cache-Control` [here's](http://pastebin.com/G6ctgjXe) what my browser sends

Comment: I tried this, there is no difference.

Comment: i tried as well i get something similar with some more js, i guess that js has to be executed to get the right page. eventualy. i believe it would be much easier with selenium, unless of course you have reasons not to use it

Comment: I tried to execute the delivered js by displaying the delivered page in a browser. Nothing happens. Selenium might be an option, thank you for this hint. Do you know some example Java code for Selenium to fetch and store a web page?

Comment: you can start [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) you can probably do it manualy as well but i think this guys know what they are doing and it will take you way too much effort whilst pretedning you are on a browser gets you there instantly

Comment: I spent a while experimenting. It seems to be a problem of cookies. If you clear cookies in Firefox and do a hard refresh, it gives the same error as the request from Java. I was able to send some artificially constructed requests from PHP with faked cookies which were successful. I think at one point I did the same in Java, but I couldn't manage to create a working automatic implementation. Sorry :(. The order of the headers is also different, although I don't think that matters. It's by far the fussiest web server I've ever had the displeasure of dealing with, and I hope it dies painfully.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to lack of JavaScript execution propably.

If you want to have full JS support, use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to browse pages - but that will instantiate a real web browser process.

You can also try with [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) - it have quite good JavaScript execution and in oppose to Selenium it is GUI-less, and a performence will be a lot better.

Comment: Can't be anything to do with JavaScript; the raw bytes returned are different.